# How to deliver props in React with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my data in materials.json

```
[
    {
        "title": "Початок роботи",
        "body": "З самого початку React був спроектований так, щоб його можна було впроваджувати поступово. Тобто ви можете додавати так мало або так багато React-у, як вам потрібно. Скористайтеся інформацією та посиланнями цього розділу, якщо просто бажаєте відчути React на смак або додаєте трохи 'інтерактивності' до простої HTML-сторінки, чи, навіть, якщо стартуєте складний React-проект.",
        "href": "https://uk.legacy.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html"
    }
...
```

For this data, I've created types:

```
type Material = {
    title: string;
    body: string;
    href: string;
};

export default Material
```

Then, I created parent component:

```
import Articles from '../../components/Articles';
import './main.css';
import materials from './../../data/materials.json';


const Main = () => {
    return (
        <main className='main'>
        <Articles data = {materials} />
        </main>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

For the last one, I created a child component:

```
import Material from "../types/material"

const Articles = (props: Material) => {

    console.log(props)
    return (
      <div>Article</div>
    
  )
}

export default Articles
```

but in Main (parent) component there is a mistake in next line

```
<Articles **data** = {materials} />
```

The mistake is

> ts(2322)

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Component definition:

```
import * as React from "react";

type Material = {
   title: string;
   body: string;
   href: string;
}
   
   const Articles:React.FC<Material> = (props) => {
      console.log(props)
      return (
         <div>Article
            <p>{props.title}</p>
         </div>
      )
   }

   export default Articles
```

Now in the parent you should easily pass props to the child component
**by assuming that the json is an array of Materials** the code can be wrote as

```
import Articles from '../../components/Articles';
import './main.css';
import materials from './../../data/materials.json';


const Main = () => {

    return (
        <main className='main'>
        {materials.map((item, i) => 
            <Articles 
               title={item.title}
               body={item.body}
               href={item.href}
               key={i}
            />
        )}
        </main>
    );
};

export default Main;
```